# Define Custom Type for Tanstack Table FilterFuntion

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, tanstack

I wrote a custom filter function for [Tanstack Table](https://tanstack.com/table/v8) which makes use of [fuse.js](https://www.fusejs.io).

However, typesript complains about all of my attempts to define the type of my custom function.

I want my Function to comply with this type definition

```js
export interface FilterFn<TData extends RowData> {
    (row: Row<TData>, columnId: string, filterValue: any, addMeta: (meta: FilterMeta) => void): boolean;
    resolveFilterValue?: TransformFilterValueFn<TData>;
    autoRemove?: ColumnFilterAutoRemoveTestFn<TData>;
}
```

This is my function. I would like to use TData instead of any but I do not know how exactly.

```js
/**
 * FilterFunction for Tanstack Table incorporating fuse's fuzzy search
 */
export const fuseFilterFn: FilterFn<any> = (
  row,
  columnId,
  filterValue,
  addMeta
) => {
  const searchPattern = filterValue.toString();

  const fuse = new Fuse([row.getValue(columnId)]);
  const searchResults = fuse.search(searchPattern);

  if (searchResults.length > 0) {
    // If any search result is found, consider the row as a match
    addMeta({ searchResults }); // Optionally, add any metadata for the search results
    return true;
  }

  return false;
};
```

This is my table

```js
interface DataTableProps<TData, TValue> {
  columns: ColumnDef<TData, TValue>[];
  data: TData[];
  columnFilters?: ColumnFilter[];
}

export function Table<TData, TValue>({
  data,
  columns,
  columnFilters = [],
}: DataTabelProps<TData, TValue>) {
  const [sorting, setSorting] = useState<ColumnSort[]>([]);
  const [filtering, setFiltering] = useState('');

  const table = useReactTable({
    data,
    columns,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
    getSortedRowModel: getSortedRowModel(),
    getPaginationRowModel: getPaginationRowModel(),
    getFilteredRowModel: getFilteredRowModel(),
    state: {
      sorting: sorting,
      globalFilter: filtering,
      columnFilters: columnFilters,
    },
    globalFilterFn: fuseFilterFn,
    onSortingChange: setSorting,
    onGlobalFilterChange: setFiltering,
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for it to not be type Any, you have to provide the type.

Example:

```
/**
* Here you define your type.
*/
type YourGenericTypeHere = {
  stringprop: string,
  numprop: number,
  recordprop: Record<string,any>,
  optional?: string,
  objectprop: Object
}

// Here you define the columnDefinition and pass the type you defined earlier
export const columns: ColumnDef<YourGenericTypeHere>[] = [{
id: "someidyouchose",
header: ({table}) => (<CustomHeaderElement/>),
// ... etc
}]
```

```
/**
 * 
 *
 * We also have to pass the Type definition to the filter, otherwise we don't 
 * know what to filter
 */
export const fuseFilterFn: FilterFn<YourGenericTypeHere> = (
  row,
  columnId,
  filterValue,
  addMeta
) => {
  const searchPattern = filterValue.toString();

  const fuse = new Fuse([row.getValue(columnId)]);
  const searchResults = fuse.search(searchPattern);

  if (searchResults.length > 0) {
    // If any search result is found, consider the row as a match
    addMeta({ searchResults }); // Optionally, add any metadata for the search results
    return true;
  }

  return false;
};
```

Then in the place where you actually render the table, provide the imported column prop

Data type should be of `YourGenericTypeHere` and columns has the same type as well.

```
<DataTable data={data} columns={columns} />
```